# How to change my "language.json" file (keys and values) without having to re-compile angular app?

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I'v just installed the ngx-translate module, it's working, my question is : after I deploy my angular 4 application, how can I change the json files (keys and values), without having to re-compile and re-déploy again.

Per example : 
My current 'en.json' file :

```
{
    "hello": "Hello World"
}
```

My app.module.ts  :

`<div>{{"hello" | translate}}</div>`

After deploying my app; I would like to change "Hello World" to "Good Morning" without re-compiling and re-deploying ! If it's possible

My app.module :

```
import {TranslateModule, TranslateLoader} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import {TranslateHttpLoader} from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
```

}

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        LoginComponent,
        LogoutComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
        HttpModule,
        // StoreModule.provideStore(createNetevenReducer, INITIAL_GLOBAL_APP_STATE),
        // StoreDevtoolsModule.instrumentOnlyWithExtension(),
        StoreModule.forRoot([]),
        EffectsModule.forRoot([]),
        !environment.production ? StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({ maxAge: 50 }) : [],
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule, // required for ng2-tag-input
        CoreModule,
        LayoutModule,
        SharedModule.forRoot(),
        RoutesModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
                deps: [HttpClient]
            }
        })
    ],
    providers: [
        AuthHttp,
        {
            provide: AuthHttp,
            useFactory: authHttpServiceFactory,
            deps: [ Http, RequestOptions ]
        },
        AuthSecurityService,
        AuthenticationService,
        UserService,
        HttpClientModule,
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy your application with multiple language.json files (en.json, de.json, fr.json) and toggle them like so:

```
constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {
    this.translate.use('en');
    // this.translate.use('fr');
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I'm able to do this, my problem is, If I wanted to change the translation for a key in the same langauge !
 Exp : I wanted to change the translation for 'hello' to 'hi' in en.json without re-compiling or reploying

Comment: I don't think it's possible to change the translation without deploying the new language.json file